# ASP NET Core MVC how to display data from SQL table in List Razor Template by UserID foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a Identity tables like AspNetUsers and others. I created migration Files with foreign key UserID to Id from AspNetUsers table for save files in Files table with logged in user Id. But in my FileManager View I see all files from Files table, but I need to display files only with UserID = Id from AspNetUsers (I mean with Id of logged in user). How Can I do it?

I think I need to edit some information in FileManager function but I'm not confident in it. If you need more code from the controller or other files in my ASP.NET Core project I can get it to you.

This code from my `WorkSpaceController` that has other functions with uploading new file and other things, but this `FileManager` function get data from context in var and displays on the `FileManagerView`:

```
private readonly TextCloudContext Context;

public IActionResult FileManager()
{
    var items = Context.Files.ToList();
    return View(items);
}
```

This is `TextCloudContext` code:

```
namespace TextCloud.Data
{
    public class TextCloudContext : IdentityDbContext<TextCloudUser>
    {
        public TextCloudContext(DbContextOptions<TextCloudContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me guys! Also, files dbo has UserId foreign key that references to Id in AspNetUsers table. I create Files table using Add-Migration command and Update-Database, so it works well and store files with current user Id, but I need to display information in ListRazorView (FileManager.cshtml) only for current logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my FileManager View I see all files from Files table, but I need to display files only with UserID = Id from AspNetUsers (I mean with Id of logged in user). How Can I do it?

To achieve the above requirement, you can try to call [UserManager.GetUserId(ClaimsPrincipal)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserid?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method to get user's id, then query files based on retrieved user id, like below.

```
//get user id of current logged-in user 
var currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

var items = Context.Files.Where(f => f.UserID == currentUserId).ToList();
return View(items);
```